# How to wait for a variable to be populated by an api request before passing it to a webpage as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and cannot seem to make this work , the topic of quiz depends on the user input... when the user presses next , I get the topic (this also takes user to the main quiz page), then i have to fetch data from the api with the topic as a parameter... I have to process the result of the fetch operation.. Then I have to pass that info to to the main quiz page... but the variable that is supposed to be populated by the fetch request is still undefined when i pass is to the main quiz page

```js
var Allquestions;
var sheetdb = require('sheetdb-node');

// create a config file
var config = {
  address: 'https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/9djmf8ydc7hwy',
};

//sheetdb
// Create new client
var client = sheetdb(config);


function downloadquestions(topic) {
  console.log(topic);
  client.read({ limit: 2, sheet: topic }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data + " in client.read func")
    processQuestions(data);
    
  }, function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
}

async function processQuestions(data) {
  console.log(data + "data in process");
  Allquestions  =  JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(Allquestions[0].Question  + " This is defined");

}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("pages/index", { title: "Home"});
});

// app.post("/" , urlencodedParser ,(req , res) => {
//   console.log(req.body.topic);  
// })

app.get("/questions", urlencodedParser , (req , res) => {
  downloadquestions(req.body.topic);
  console.log(Allquestions + " this is undefined");
  res.render("/pages/quizpage" , {Allquestions})

})
```

Comment: Perhaps place everything in a containing function that invokes async and then await everything inside it.

Or, you could use a Promise.all() and resolve the functions.

Comment: `client.read(`   ->  `return client.read(`  otherwise you break the promise chain..  You can then do ->  `await downloadquestions(...`,  and just change `(req, res) => ` to `async (req, res) => `

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code, you have a broken promise chain,  `client.read(` is a promise, and that promise is going nowhere.  You either return it, or `await` it.  To be able to `await` your will need to also mark your route `(req, res)` as `async` too.

Your code is a little mixed up, you have `Allquestions` as a global var, this isn't great for multi-user, as the last topic is going to override this each time.

Also try and avoid swallowing exceptions in utility functions, try and keep your exception handling at the top level, eg. in your case inside your req/res handler.

So with all this in mind, your refactored code could look something like ->

```
const sheetdb = require('sheetdb-node');

// create a config file
const config = {
  address: 'https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/9djmf8ydc7hwy',
};

//sheetdb
// Create new client
const client = sheetdb(config);

async function downloadquestions(topic) {
  const data = await client.read({ limit: 2, sheet: topic });
  return processQuestions(data);
}

function processQuestions(data) {
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("pages/index", { title: "Home"});
});

app.get("/questions", urlencodedParser , async (req , res) => {
  try {
    const allQuestions = await downloadquestions(req.body.topic);
    res.render("/pages/quizpage" , {Allquestions});
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.end('There was an error'); 
  }
})
```